# Is there a efficient way in Julia to pause execution of a program until the next day?

Tags: date, julia, duration, pause

Suppose I'm running a program and each day I want to pause the program after X iterations until the start of the next calendar day. The amount of time the program will have to be paused each day will vary because I do not know when X iterations will be completed on a given day.

**Question** Is there a simple way to pause the program so that it will restart at the start of the next day E.S.T?

I thought of using the sleep() function.  The problem is the interval the program would have to pause each day is different so I can't put in an absolute time value.  So I thought conceptually it would something like this might work.

```
while true 
    # run function until X loops
    # sleep(Minute(tomorrow's date - now())
```

But I'm not sure how I would get the start of tomorrow's date from Julia or if this is the most efficient approach.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally use `cron` like @pfitzseb said.
However, the simplest nice Julia code could be:

```
function once_a_time(f, interval)
    repeat = Ref(true) 
    task = @async begin 
        sleep(5) # some calculated time to start
        while repeat[]
            @async f()
            sleep(interval)
        end
    end
    return (;task, repeat)
end
```

This function will execute `f` in given fixed intervals regardless of previous assumptions. This code uses green threads so it assumes that `f` execution time is smaller that the value of `interval` (or `f` is just mostly I/O).
The function returns a handle to the task as well as reference to the `repeat` variable so you can stop your scheduler from an outside code.

Let us now test it:

```
julia> task, rep = once_a_time(()->println("hello ",round(Int,time()) % 1000), 5)
(task = Task (runnable) @0x000000001b69b850, repeat = Base.RefValue{Bool}(true))

julia> hello 347
hello 352
hello 357
hello 362
julia> rep[]=false
false
```

Comment: Thanks this is great!  Sorry a few follow up questions because I'm not very schooled in this.  We are returning task and repeat just so we can control the function with outside code correct?  If I wanted the task to enter the scheduler queue upon execution of the function I would just do something like "@async while repeat[ ]  f()..." without referencing a task variable?  Also what does the semicolon operator in front of the task do in the return function?   Final question why is it good to add "repeat[]" as condition in the while loop? Won't the loop terminate on it's own if repeat == false?

Comment: Yes! we return `repeat` to control with outside code. If you want just to enter the task you remove the first `@async` in my code. The semicolon at `return (; a,b)` returns a `NamedTuple`. We assign `repeat = Ref(true) ` so `repeat[]` yields `true` until we change it in exterrnal code to `false` (see my code). This is how the external control works in my code.

Comment: Got it thanks so much...and just to be clear the code still would work if I removed 'repeat[]' from the line 'repeat[ ] && sleep(interval)' correct?   So long as i have 'while repeat[]' i can shut it off with an external code.  So the "repeat[]" within the while loop is just a redundancy or does it play some other function?

Comment: Yes you can remove `repeat[] &&` from the line `repeat[ ] && sleep(interval)` - I have actually updated my answer because lines after `@async` get executed anyway immedietaly so this `repeat[] &&` was in fact redundant. Thanky you.

Answer (score 4):

Generally I'd recommend using some OS-level scheduler (like cron) for this instead of a long running process, but you can easily figure out the time your program needs to sleep with

```
julia> DateTime(today()) + Day(1) - now()
52522991 milliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks this is great!  Sorry just curious what are the upsides of using an OS-level scheduler vs doing something like this natively in Julia?

Comment: @phntm Generally, an OS-level scheduler will be much more robust than a Julia process. For instance, they are designed to handle your computer going to sleep or even rebooting.